# How to detect a news article belong to which location?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

Suppose that I have a news article that in the text there are some locations.
I can extract all the locations with NER like Spacy.

But, in addition to NER, the output
should return a list of found locations in the news article along a percentage that the model thinks the news article belongs to the corresponding location. For example, the model outputs New York, Los Angeles, and London for the found locations and returns 0.3, 0.6, and 0.1 for the percentages, respectively. This in turn means that the model has found three locations in the news body and would assign a 60 percent probability that the news revolves around Los Angeles.

Do anyone have a solution about this?
One can use a third party library too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: @TylerH You can search by nlp keyword in stackoverflow.